# QtCreator [Qt 5.9.x ] QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

This was bugging me for a while, and I am just submitting this if someone else gets the same bug as well, and as far as I could see, it's not an uncommon issue.

If you ever move your Qt QML code to a different machine, and after you run it from a Qt Creator, you get anything like this:

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
>   qrc:/main.qml:14 Type ApplicationWindow unavailable
>   [path-to-your-qt]qt5/5.9.3/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.qml:41 plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick.Templates": Cannot load library >
>   [path-to-your-qt]qt5/5.9.3/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Templates.2/libqtquicktemplates2plugin.so:
>   [path-to-your-qt]qt5/5.9.3/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Templates.2/libqtquicktemplates2plugin.so: symbol _ZN15QQuickContainer17componentCompleteEv, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5 with link time reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running Qt Creator executable directly instead of running the shell file , i.e. run:

**[qt5-dir]Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator** 
instead of 
**[qt5-dir]Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator.sh**

qtcreator.sh fiddles with LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and there it might start using your system Qt libraries, which are 95% older than the Qt you've just installed using your Qt Installer